# Ionic social share is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, socialshare

I am trying to follow the tutorial example in ionic with the line

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareWithOptions(options, onSuccess, onError);
```

but I keep getting

```
ionic.bundle.js:20306 TypeError: Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined
```

I guess I am missing something in the `app.js` to include the library?

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','leaflet-directive', 'ngCordova', ... ?
```

Do I need to load it in the above line? 
Do I have to load it into the controller as a module? I didnt find that on the tutorial and it's not clear?

I tried `cordova plugin add` multiple times, either as the package name or through git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was looking into the wrong documentation. If using ionic, check [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/) docs rather then the offical package documentations. They are not consistent.

I had to add `$cordovaSocialSharing` to my controller and it worked on the device, not in the simulator and neither in my dev browser chrome.